# Instailling Rails 2.0.0 extconf.rb failure on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install rails 2.0.0 on my computer. I already have already installed ruby on my computer, running the

```
ruby -v
```

command returns

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]
```

Now, I'm trying to install rails 2.0.0 by running

```
gem install rails
```

However, I am running into an error:

```
    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:515:in `try_link0'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:813:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

4th line up says I need to install development tools, so I downloaded the dev kit from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ for my 64 bit windows, and ran the following commands without issue:

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
```

However, I still got the same error after running gem rails install... .am I installing the wrong development tools or something? I'm not sure what's going wrong

Additionally I'm using pik to control my ruby version, if that information is relevant.

Note: I checked out another possible solution that said that my userfolder had spaces in it, causing the install to go wonky, but my user account doesn't have spaces in it, so that didn't help.

*edit: the mkmf file with more info:

```
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -march=native conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

Comment: I'm having similar issues so if you solved your problem(which i assume you must have by now), can you please post the solution

Comment: This doesn't have a terribly happy ending. I ended up installing a partition of Ubuntu and running ruby/rails off that. You can also try installing from http://rubyinstaller.org/. It didn't have the version I needed but when I tried it did ruby 2.0 and rails 3.2(?) well, if memory serves.

Comment: However, I will say that I suspect that it's due to my root file naming convention. I did some reading and apparently the installer has some issues when your user folder has spaces in it (eg. 'John Doe')... it was too much of a hassle to change my root user folder to experiment. Windows is a second class citizen for ruby/rails, I feel.

Comment: same here had to install ubuntu